# UnityMain not showing in Systrace

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, telemetry, systrace

I ran a Systrace and opened 2 Unity apps. I configured atrace to use these 2 categories: "am", and "view". However, when I go to view it in the trace viewer I see the Unity apps but I don't see UnityMain.

I tried using 2 additional categories: "gfx", and "input". But this time in the trace viewer I don't see Unity apps at all.

What is going on here? Here is [Systrace for Unity](https://github.com/Over17/UnitySystracePlugin) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to target a specific Unity app by using Systrace's app flag `--app=<name of unity package>`. I used "am", and "view" categories.